# bq Aquaris e4.5 lockout

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I changed my password by way of the passwd command in the terminal app, and it seems to have broken things.

There was a pin securing the phone prior to the passphrase being implemented, but now all I'm offered to unlock the screen is a numeric keypad. Is there some way to work around this problem. Obviously if there's a way around it that would be a sensitive thing to know but as this seems to be a glitch I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

It expects you to enter passcode to unlock , in case you can't recall it only option I can think of resetting phone to factory settings.